# PHP non-blocking exclusive lock

Tags: php, locking, flock

I would like to use exclusive/shared, both blocking and non-blocking locks like these found in `flock()`. How can this be achieved using semaphores?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the use case.

If you are on only one server, use a lock file.

```
function doSomething() {
  $file = /temp/path/somthing.lock;
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    return false;
  }
  touch($file);
  // Safely mess with things
  unlink($file);
}
```

If you have multiple web servers, e.g. behind a load balancer, the same thing can be accomplished by using a table in mysql.

```
function doSomething() {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM locks WHERE name='something'");
  $res = mysqli_query($query);
  if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    return false;
  }
  $query = "INSERT INTO locks (name) VALUES ('something')";
  mysqli_query($query);
  // Safely mess with things
  $query = "DELETE FROM locks WHERE name='something'");
  mysqli_query($query);
}
```

Memcache is another obvious candidate with multiple machine support.

You should not use ACP, because it is intended for caching only. This means you do not have control when ACP storage gets deleted, it could happen at any time.

You can also use semaphores, however the same caveats as with lock files apply if you use more than one server.

I would recommend creating `lock($key)`, `is_locked($key)` and `release($key)` functions, and then religiously use them throughout your project. That way you can start with lock files (quick to implement), but then upgrade to something better later without editing the rest of your code. If you want to get really fancy, you can implement them as methods of a logger object that you put in a known location of your code.

Comment: Tnx for examples, but I'm afraid that they are subject to race condition? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: Well, yes, in a sense they are. However, that is not so much because of the examples, but a side effect of the IP protocol, that makes no guarantees on timing. The best you can do is prevent more than one request from getting through.

Comment: @cmc What? Site effect of IP? For MySQL you simply have a UNIQUE index on `locks.name` and the first client which successfully can create the record holds the lock. Any further request will result in a duplicate key error.

Comment: @Shi: How is that not a race condition? Can you determine which request will be first? Also, I prefer to avoid errors rather than catch them, so my logs show the serious stuff.

Comment: @cmc It depends on the aspect you want to emphasise. Of course both requests will race for the lock, but as the operation is atomic, only one can get it. So in a sense of "under special circumstances, both requests can get the lock", it is not a race condition. And regarding your "errors" - there is no way of not having an error if you do not want to do blocking locking. The instance which requests the lock but cannot get it will signal an error. If you use a database table, the error is called "duplicate key", if you use some Unix system call, it is "EEXIST".